# the ferret error in rails project

Tags: ruby, ferret, acts-as-ferret

I use the plugin of acts_as_ferret. when i use find_with_ferret,i got this problem.I got the error messages from the console like this

```
 EOFError in 'DestroysController save destroy require reason'
End-of-File Error occured at <except.c>:117 in xpop_context
Error occured in store.c:216 - is_refill
    current pos = 0, file length = 0
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I got the answer , we should rebuild the index of the model.